# How to optimize boot up time for android automotive

Tags: android, android-source, automotive

I am using nxp imx8 for android automotive amd my task is to reduce/optimize android bootup time programmatically. Which code to change for the bootup time in aosp

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on AOSP documentation on how to tackle this issue:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/boot-times